# Laravel Console Command Test use Option

Tags: laravel, phpunit

I tested the console command but `'--forced'` option not working.

I think that `--forced` is OK because the following code exists in vendor/symfony/console/Input/InputOption.php

```
if (0 === strpos($name, '--')) {
    $name = substr($name, 2);
}
```

I set 'forced' and got the same result.Can you help me?

**Console Command**

```
class SendOrderCommand extends Command
{
    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'command:send_order {mode} {template_id} {order_id?} {--forced}';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'send order command';

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        $this->line('');
        $this->line('===========================================');
        $this->line('Running DEFAULT task [SendOrderCommand:handle]');
        $this->line('===========================================');
        $this->line('');

        $mode = $this->argument('mode');
        $templateId = $this->argument('template_id');
        $orderId = $this->argument('order_id');
        $forced = $this->option("forced");
```

**Test Code**

```
class SendOrderCommandTest extends TestCase
{
    public function testSendOrderCommandSuccessRealForced()
    {
        $output = $this->execute(['mode' => 'real', 'template_id' => 1, 'order_id' => 1, '--forced']);
        $this->assertFalse(strpos(trim($output->fetch()), 'already instructed') !== false);
    }



$this->assertFalse(strpos(trim($output->fetch()), 'already instructed') !== false);
```

This test expect "false"(the result dose not contains "already instructed"), But result is "true".

[Expect]

```
[common] php artisan --env=local command:send_order real 10007 10002 --forced                                                                                                                                                                                                
===========================================
Running DEFAULT task [SendOrderCommand:handle]
===========================================
```

No Error.

[Actual]

```
[common] php artisan --env=local command:send_order real 10007 10002 --forced                                                                                                                                                                                            
===========================================
Running DEFAULT task [SendOrderCommand:handle]
===========================================

It's already instructed. If forcibly instructed, use the forced option.
```

'--forced' option must skip  already instructed.

That is to say, '--forced' option dose not receive 'command:send_order'.

Comment: What exactly does "not working" mean? How does it fail when you do what? Does it work as you expect when you don't specify "--forced" option? You may also want to add in your question how it fails when you run `php artisan tinker`.

Comment: Thanks.
I updated the Question text  for your comment.

Comment: The case is still not reproducible. The printed comment like 'If forcibly instructed' does not appear anywhere in your code, but only in the result. Also, to use TestCase adds just complexity. Where do you put the test code and what is your env, etc, etc. Instead, attach the result of `php artisan tinker`; then it has a far better chance to be reproducible. Also, I recommend you to delete unnecessary parts in your code, like excessive comment lines, and present the bare minimum set to reproduce the case.

Comment: Oops, sorry, *not* `php artisan tinker`, but `php artisan YourCommand` .  For your information, your Test Code doesn't look correct. The associated array contains an element `0 => '--forced'` Please present the case so that it isolates the problem of your command and is unrelated to whatever your test environment or code.

Answer (score 0):

You should use this in your test:

```php
$this->artisan('command:send_order', [
   'mode' => 'value for mode',
   'template_id' => 123,
   'order_id' => 123,
   'forced' => true
];
```

Further reading:
https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/console-tests